# How to do nested cross-validation with LASSO in caret or tidymodels?

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret, lasso-regression, tidymodels

## Goal

I'd like to implement a LASSO model and check its viability on a training set according to the schematic shown [here](https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/51156277e4b0b8b2ffe11c00/1504402121697-RVE0F0XJXBIVL0U32DCU/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kDqvPxG_YaRae8DHeJARus9Zw-zPPgdn4jUwVcJE1ZvWQUxwkmyExglNqGp0IvTJZUJFbgE-7XRK3dMEBRBhUpzDjxdSXYICZ-3PDzJihLudK7vln90GRJQge7AhcGsPGR3SbnJMBDOacOPYuZm-JzI/diagram.png?format=750w). (Schematic destription: all data is split into testing and training sets. The training set is split via 5-fold cross-validation (CV) into resamples. where 10-fold CV is performed on each resample to find optimal lambdas.) The testing set is not available yet.

I'd like to LASSO model and check its performance using nested CV with inner CV to obtain optimal lambda (analysis and assessment) via a grid searches and outer CV to compare resamples 1, 2, 3 etc.

## Caret with 'repeatedcv'

The train-control with 'repeatedcv' from Caret allows to specify number and repeats.

```
lambdas = 10^seq(-3, -1, length = 20)
trControl = trainControl(
      'repeatedcv', 
      number = 10, 
      repeats = 5, 
      search = 'grid'
)
tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 1, lambda = lambdas)
lasso = train(
       PD ~ ., data = selection, 
       method = 'glmnet',
       trControl = trControl, 
       tuneGrid = tuneGrid
)

lasso$results
```

With the code above, caret results is a dataframe with 20 rows. Presumably one row for each point on the defined grid. However, I'd like caret to **find one optimal lambda per grid search using 10-fold (number = 10) CV** and then compare the optimal lambdas, as the bold process was performed multiple times (repeats = 5).

Answer (score 3):

You can implement nested resampling in tidymodels using `nested_cv()`:

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> ── Attaching packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels 0.1.0 ──
#> ✓ broom     0.5.6      ✓ recipes   0.1.12
#> ✓ dials     0.0.7      ✓ rsample   0.0.7 
#> ✓ dplyr     1.0.0      ✓ tibble    3.0.1 
#> ✓ ggplot2   3.3.1      ✓ tune      0.1.0 
#> ✓ infer     0.5.1      ✓ workflows 0.1.1 
#> ✓ parsnip   0.1.1      ✓ yardstick 0.0.6 
#> ✓ purrr     0.3.4
#> ── Conflicts ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
#> x purrr::discard() masks scales::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()  masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()     masks stats::lag()
#> x recipes::step()  masks stats::step()

results <- nested_cv(mtcars, 
                     outside = vfold_cv(repeats = 5), 
                     inside = bootstraps(times = 25))
results
#> # Nested resampling:
#> #  outer: 10-fold cross-validation repeated 5 times
#> #  inner: Bootstrap sampling
#> # A tibble: 50 x 4
#>    splits         id      id2    inner_resamples  
#>    <list>         <chr>   <chr>  <list>           
#>  1 <split [28/4]> Repeat1 Fold01 <tibble [25 × 2]>
#>  2 <split [28/4]> Repeat1 Fold02 <tibble [25 × 2]>
#>  3 <split [29/3]> Repeat1 Fold03 <tibble [25 × 2]>
#>  4 <split [29/3]> Repeat1 Fold04 <tibble [25 × 2]>
#>  5 <split [29/3]> Repeat1 Fold05 <tibble [25 × 2]>
#>  6 <split [29/3]> Repeat1 Fold06 <tibble [25 × 2]>
#>  7 <split [29/3]> Repeat1 Fold07 <tibble [25 × 2]>
#>  8 <split [29/3]> Repeat1 Fold08 <tibble [25 × 2]>
#>  9 <split [29/3]> Repeat1 Fold09 <tibble [25 × 2]>
#> 10 <split [29/3]> Repeat1 Fold10 <tibble [25 × 2]>
#> # … with 40 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

For an outline of how to train and assess models on nested resamples like this, check out [this article on `tidymodels.org`](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/work/nested-resampling/).

Comment: I didn't manage to adapt the [code of the suggested article](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/work/nested-resampling/) to the LASSO modeling routine and unfortunately nested_cv does not work with tune() yet. I ended up using the mlr3 package. ([Code example of nested CV LASSO with mlr3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62323004/how-to-access-and-compare-lasso-model-coefficients-with-mlr3-glmnet-learner))

Comment: In your example and in the nested_cv documentation we can see how to sample the data but not how to aumatically fit a model on each nested fold.

Comment: Yes, in tidymodels we don't have support for automatic tuning with nested resampling. Instead, we show how to [write a function and apply it across the nested resamples](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/work/nested-resampling/).